# HTML/CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

So I have the following code:

```
<body>
<div id="page1" style="page-break-after:always;position:relative;">
  <img ... id="img1" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:750px"></img>
  ...
</div>
<div id="page2" style="page-break-after:always;position:relative;">
  <img ... id="img2" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:750px"></img>
  ...
</div>
</body>
```

This displays fine, with page 2 below page 1. However, when I change img1's position to absolute, why does it make page2 overlap with page1 (brings it up to the position of page1)? From what I understand, setting position to absolute will bring it out of the normal flow of the page, but isn't img1 contained within page1? Why is page1 being taken out of the normal flow (I'm assuming this is what is happening)?

Comment: when img1 is taken out of the flow, page1 shrinks down to the minimum height it needs to be. So page2 moves up to the bottom of page1.

Comment: I've turned that comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the img1 position to absolute, it moves out of the 'normal flow', like you said. So the page1 element shrinks down to its minimum height and width. This causes the page2 element to move up to the bottom of page1.

So your page1, page2, and img2 are all in the correct places per your layout, it's only your img1 that is out of its regular spot.

I've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fqanhkv/) that shows what is happening. Normally, the 'img' boxes are inside their parent page boxes.  But if you set img1 to `position:absolute` it moves out of the logical flow, so it's parent, page1, shrinks back down to minimum size.